# When mentioning several items each of which is “Aᵢ”, should I use “Aᵢ’s” with an apostrophe or “Aᵢs” without one?

Tags: orthography, apostrophe, mathematics

Here is a sentence I’m about to write:

> Given a family of sets { *Aᵢ* : 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n* }, we may assume that the **Aᵢ’s** are disjoint.

I mean the sets in the family do not intersect with each other. I am wondering whether I should use *Aᵢ’s* or *Aᵢs*.

Is there any agreed-upon guideline for writing this that will not confuse the reader?

Comment: A_i's or A_1's? The former read aloud would be "A is".

Comment: Can you please clarify: *Given a family of sets {A_1,...,A_n}, we may assume that the A_i's are disjoint.* **A_1** is not the same as **A_i**: How are they related?

Comment: In your setup, A_i's need the apostrophe. I'd reword so I didn't need it. Somehow. Given a family of sets {A_1,...,A_n}, assume that **all sets** are disjoint.

Comment: I fixed it to clarify: The sets are A_i for i = 1,...,n.

Comment: Why not use *they*? Given a family of sets {A_i: 1 ≤ i ≤ n}, we may assume they are disjoint.

Comment: You could always say "the sets A_i are disjoint".

Comment: Ask a mathematician.

Comment: I might write "the A_i are disjoint" as I essentially did [on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3997925/6460)

Answer (score 2):

Never, never, never, never, never use apostrophes for plurals. It's one of the basic errors that even vaguely knowledgeable grammar nerds love to pounce on.

More fundamentally you cannot (in mathematics) say that "a set is disjoint" or that "all the sets in this family are disjoint". "Disjointness" is not an attribute of one set. Only pairs of sets (or groups of sets) can be disjoint.

Some suggestions:

> ...assume that the sets are pairwise disjoint.

meaning that any two sets have no elements in common, or

> ...assume that the family is disjoint.

meaning that the intersection of all the sets in the family is null.

In general you can describe an attribute of each set saying "such that all the sets are...". If you absolutely must use a plural then adding an "s" with no other chracter is the accepted way. Since that is confusing here, choosing a different naming convention for the sets would be preferable.

Comment: Generally, if you say a family of sets is disjoint in mathematics, it usually means that every pair is disjoint. [See dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disjoint) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets)

Comment: It used to be quite common to encounter, in a textbook, something like "Count the number of I's in the following paragraph."  This is less common in recent years, but at least at one time was considered "proper".

Comment: It's OK to use apostrophes for letter plurals generally, but not in math. An apostrophe looks too much like a prime mark.